# how to implicitly link (or reference) two projects from one solution in msvc 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I making this library(.dll) and I created another project(.exe) to test it.

How do I do that in MSVS 2010??

Googling it for about an hour and I still haven't the answer. So I decide to ask it here.

I do the linking by typing the whole path explicitly from `#include` directive.

From project2 (.exe)

```
#include "C:\...\project2.h"
```

How could I make this possible:

```
#include "project2.h"
```

???

**EDIT**

In addition to my question

*1*

My dynamic(.dll) library has linked into a static(.lib) library.

And I explicitly code the linking there and is already present in header file(.h) to be imported.

Should I still link it to the other project?

*2*

My library is implemented in an OOP manner.

Which is better to use, (.dll) or (.lib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure it out..

Just include "..\" before the file or folder to move up one directory

Answer (score 0):

I use property sheets for that.

For any library you create, you also create a property sheet. In that property sheet, you add the library's include path to the global include path, its library path to the global library path, and if you don't use pragma-driven auto-imports, its import library to the global import libraries.

If the library has dependencies on other libraries, you additionally import those libraries' property sheets. You may have to do some crazy stuff to get rid of compiler msbuild if you have multiple paths to one property sheet, but Google can help you there (just google the warning message).

The main issue here is how to specify the paths. It works for me because my development environment has a single directory where all solutions live, and all solutions are exactly one level below that main directory. So I can always find the headers for library foo in solution bar by using $(SolutionDir)..\bar\foo\include as the include path. This may not work in your case.

In Visual Studio 2012, you should be able to use $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory) to get the directory the property sheet file is in. I'm not sure if this works in 2010; I couldn't find documentation for it, but it may still be there. You should try.